# Since System.Half is not a primitive, how can I make a const of it?

Tags: c#, constants

The rather new-ish `System.Half` is *not a primitive* so you can't make a compile time `const` of it to use as an optional arg. Currently there's discussion of making it a primitive in a later C# release, but it hasn't happened yet. Is there some work around to do something like this?:

```
// This gets the compile error: The type 'Half' can't be declared const
const Half MyVal = 42; 

void MyMethod(Half myArg = MyVal)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't make it a constant. The only option is to make it a static readonly field

Comment: Right now, `Half` is essentially [a wrapper for a `ushort`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Half.cs,7895d5942d33f974).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `readonly` instead of `const`, something like this:

```
// Unlike const, readonly will be computed in run time
static readonly Half MyVal = (Half)42; 

// Since MyVal is not a const we can't use it in the declaration ...
void MyMethod(Half myArg)
{
    ...
}

// ... but we can use myArg in the overload 
void MyMethod() => MyMethod(MyVal);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1wCir)